# MulticastSocket to send TCP Packet

Tags: java, sockets

I want to broadcast/multicast a msg to multiple clients, However my msg size is somewhat bigger than UDP datagram packet length.
So when I used `MulticastSocket`, I got `java.io.IOException: Message too long` exception.

I know I've to use TCP packet for that, but can I use `MulticastSocket` to send TCP data?
What could be the alternative?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: No, you cannot multicast tcp.  You can use multiple udp packets but you will have to embed sequence information so that you can re-assemble them in correct order on systems where all are received.

Comment: Actually I want to send an Object over socket, so I can't fragment it into multiple udp packet. Whats the approach to send TCP packet to multiple clients?

Comment: Send it to one client at a time.

Comment: You can still fragment it, however, you most hold onto received pieces for re-assembly, and will only be able to re-assemble it into a complete Object on clients where all of the pieces are received.